# Animating a Bootstrap Progress bar keeps going for some reason

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, android-progressbar

My progress bar HTML looks like:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div style="width: 10%; overflow: hidden;" class="bar" id="status-progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

When I run `$("#status-progress-bar").stop().animate({   width: '10%' }, 5000);` on it, the width jumps to 54% (steadily) then animates down to 10%. I'm not sure why this is or what to do about it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some trouble too animating bootstrap progress bars.
Sometimes the width jumps to 100%, or a random position when animating.
And also there is a problem if you want the animation to be `linear` instead of the default `swing`.

What I've done is adding `style="transition:none;"` to the `.bar` like that:

```
<div id="upload-progress" class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" style="transition:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Now it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have uncovered a bug or some unintended behavior with the way the bar is animating.  If you remove the `width: 10%` from your html then the javascript works as expected. (not sure why you are starting at 10%).

FWIW, What it appears to be doing is animating 10% on top of the existing 10% then realizing it should only be at 10% then scaling back.

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div style="overflow: hidden;" class="bar" id="status-progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well - I start at 0%, but I animate it to 10% then again to 50%, then to 75% and so on based on certain events. So what can I do about this?

Comment: I do not know what events you are using, but I tried using a click event to increase the status and didn't see the same issue you were experiencing.  http://jsbin.com/owugupU/1/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oVeBEDE/1/ - if you click click 2 or 3 times in a row, you get the error

Comment: @Shamoon,  I took a look at the dom while it was animating and it seems that it is converting the sizing from percentage, then back to percentage.  I tried using just raw numbers(100 etc) and I did not get the issue to replicate. Kind of a pain but it "works" http://jsbin.com/oVeBEDE/3/